# change hypothesis of a proposition or generalize

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, vector-analysis

I have the following claim:

*If $A$ is a closed set that contains every number rational $r$ in $[0,1]$, show that $[0,1]\subset A$.*

The prove is easy, Since the set A is closed, all its points are accumulation points, we have to show that every point in $x\in [0,1]$ is an accumulation point in $A$, which I already did.

My question is whether I can weaken the hypothesis, and whether the proposition remains true.
I've thought about changing the assumption that set $A$ is open, but I'm not sure if that's true.
Any comment is welcome, or if it is possible to deepen the proposition further.

Comment: There are open sets of $\Bbb R$ that contain $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ and yet do not contain $[0,1]$.

Comment: Maybe you could get by with less than *all* rationals?

Comment: Excuse me @HennoBrandsma Could you help me with an example that the interval $[0,1]$ is not contained in an open interval

Comment: Let $[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q = \{r_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ an enumeration. Take an open interval around every $r_n$ of smaller and smaller radius (Like $\frac{1}{3}^{n+1}$ etc.). Their union will be open but won't contain all of $[0,1]$ if you've ensured that the sum of the lengths is $\le \frac12$, say. It's doable.

Comment: Thank you very much, @HennoBrandsma.